# Htaccess how to properly route to the correct directory?

Tags: .htaccess, routes

I have a folder structure on my server like so:

```
.htaccess
index.php
[website1]
    [placeholder]
        index.php
[website2]
[website3]
```

All domains web1.com, web2.com and web3.com link to this directory. I like the htaccess to route them to the proper directory. So web1.com goes to website1, web2.com goes to website2, etc.

However I like the URL to be something like http://www.web1.com/ and it should show the content in website1.

Now I have the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(web1.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.web1.com/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.web1.com)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website1/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.web1.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/?|index.php)$ website1/index.php [L]
```

This works, however if you go to http://www.web1.com/placeholder it will display the following in the URL:

```
http://www.web1.com/website1/placeholder/
```

Of course it's preferred to see the URL as http://www.web1.com/placeholder. For the record http://www.web1.com/placeholder/ does show the proper page.

How can I fix this? It's driving me nuts.

**EDIT (ANSWER):**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.web1.com)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^website1/(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/
```

Not sure if this is the proper way to do it, but it seems to work.

Comment: Have you tried the P flag to the rewrite rule to make the request proxy?

Comment: Why would that be a good thing? I am not doing anything with proxy's.

Comment: If you add the P flag to the rewrite rule then Apache will internally proxy the request preserving the original url to the browser.  Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: I fixed it with:RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.web1.com)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^website1/(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/